# In Eclipse, I'm trying to set a breakpoint, but only getting a 'set bookmark name' popup

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Not sure if this is due to mixing Eclipse with ROS, but while trying to set a breakpoint by double clicking in the left border of the editor on a line in my C++ code I keep getting a popup menu for setting a bookmark name. Right mouse clicking in the left border displays a menu to add a bookmark or a task. This occurs both in the C/C++ and Debug perspectives.

I am able to run the program in Eclipse to completion, I would just like to get use to using the debugging facilities before moving on to more complicated stuff.

I have Eclipse v 4.4.1, running on Ubuntu 12.04. and it is setup (through the use of catkin) to develop ROS (hydro) apps as described at http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203459/in-eclipse,-i%27m-trying-to-set-a-breakpoint,-but-only-getting-a-%27set-bookmark-name%27-popup/) by [MikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21679/mikes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-02-19

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2015-02-22**:
Nothing to do with ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In going back to my development, when I started a debug session, in the upper right hand corner of the debug perspective there is a breakpoints view - this showed that the breakpoints I tried to set actually did get set, even though I didn't get the popup window I was expecting. So, it doesn't work as shown in the tutorials I've seen but it does allow breakpoints. I am considering this solved.

---

Originally posted by [MikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21679/mikes/) with karma: 16 on 2015-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0